# Point in the closure iff distance to the set is zero.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

**Exercise.** Let $d$ be a pseudo-metric in $X$ and for $A,B \subset X$ we have $d(A,B) := \inf\{d(a,b): a \in A,b \in B\}$. Show that:
\begin{equation*}
x \in \overline{A} \Leftrightarrow d(x,A) = 0.
\end{equation*}
**What I've got so far.** I was able to prove the $(\Rightarrow)$ implication, i.e., that $x \in \overline{A} \Rightarrow d(x,A) = 0$, but I am having some trouble proving the other implication, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
d(x,A) = 0 \Rightarrow x \in \overline{A}
\end{equation*}
I've tried the following: assume $d(x,A)=0$ then we have that $\inf\{d(x,a): a \in A\}=0$. It is obvious that
\begin{equation*}
\exists a \in A: d(x,a)=0 \Rightarrow x = a \in A \Rightarrow x \in \overline{A}
\end{equation*}
If $\nexists a \in A:d(x,a) = 0,$ there is at least one $a(\neq x)\in A: d(x,a) <r$, with $r\rightarrow 0$, which implies that $a \in V_r(x)$. $r$ is as small as we want and thus $\forall r>0, a \in V_r(x) \Rightarrow x \in A' \Rightarrow x \in \overline{A}$.

I am not quite sure this is right and was looking for a verification or help in getting to the solution

Comment: Please show your attempt; by just saying im having trouble your question is likely to be deleted (Im sorry but that's really a general rule) if you want you can show your solution of the first part

Comment: @Math thanks for your feedback, I've edited the question with what I've done so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's me, but I don't get why $\exists a\in A$ such that $d(a,x)=0$ should imply $a=x$. That's the thing not holding in pseudometric spaces with respect to metric ones.

Hint: try by contradiction.

Spoiler:

If you suppose $x\notin \bar{A}$, then $x$ is in the complement, which is clearly open and this allows you to find a basic open neighborhood $V$ contained in this complement, that is $r>0$ such that $V=V_r(x)\ni x$ and $V\cap \bar{A}=\varnothing$.

Therefore, I claim that $d(x,A)\geq r>0$ (and hence not $0$). Again by contradiction, suppose to have $d(x,A)=\text{inf}\{d(x,y);\text{ }y\in A\}<r$, and find then a $y\in A$ such that $d(x,y)<r$ (such a $y$ has to exists, otherwise the $\text{inf}$ should be $\geq r$). This concludes because $y$ is in $V\cap A$, giving a contradiction to emptyness of the latter.